# Generating correlated ordinal data

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I'm using the package GenOrd for generating correlated ordinal data. The basic idea is to get correlated ordinal data with correlation 0.5, now I want to repeat the whole code for 1000 times and save the results of correlation, to see how close I can get to the correlation of 0.5, then change the sample size and the Marginal probabilities and see what changes.

```
library(GenOrd)
R<-matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),2,2)
Marginal<-list(c(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9),c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5))
DataOrd<-ordsample(100,Marginal,R)
correlation<-cor(DataOrd)
correlation[1,2] # 0.5269
```

Comment: Have you looked into `?replicate`?

Comment: I just want to have the results of 1000 simulations, so 1000 different correlations, to see how close I can get to 0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
sim.cor <- function(R, Marginal, n, K)
{
   res <- numeric(length = K)
   for(i in 1:K)
      res[i] <- cor(ordsample(n, Marginal, R))[1,2]
   res
}
```

where `n` is the sample size and `K` is the number of times you want to repeat. So, in your example, you can call this function and save the result (a vector of size `K` with the correlations) in an object:

```
set.seed(1234)
correlations <- sim.cor(R = R, Marginal = Marginal, n = 100, K = 1000)
mean(correlations)
[1] 0.5009389
```

A faster and more elegant solution is to use the `replicate` function as suggested by jaysunice3401:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
correlations <- replicate(n = 1000, expr = cor(ordsample(n, Marginal, R))[1,2])
mean(correlations)
[1] 0.5009389
```

I hope this can help!

Comment: perfect solution. Appreciate your help